# UnicodeDecodeError when opening Python in console

Tags: python, utf-8, console, ascii

When I type `python` to open it in the console, I am getting an `UnicodeDecodeError`, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I have the same problem in all the consoles: cmd, cmder and anaconda.

I realized this started to happen after trying to save a `pandas` dataframe to a file modifying its encoding (I tried `ascii` and the default, `utf-8`).

Is there a way to fix it without having to uninstall and install Python again?

Comment: Does it also happen if you activate the conda environment before starting Python, as the warning suggests?

Comment: The history file is corrupt and must be deleted; as @lenz suggests, you should also ensure that you actually activate the environment.